# Synergy client drops and reconnects at UAC dialog

Tags: windows, uac, synergy, secure-desktop

I've been using Synergy for a while at work to connect my XP machine (the host) to my Win 7 laptop (the client). I previously was having issues with using Synergy and the UAC prompt, as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/97699/how-to-get-uac-to-co-operate-with-synergy2), and have had no issues since, until recently.

I upgraded to Synergy 1.4.10 and now am seeing odd behavior whenever a UAC prompt appears on my laptop.

When the UAC prompt appears on my laptop, Synergy momentarily drops its connection to my laptop, causing my mouse and keyboard focus to revert to my host machine (the XP machine). After about a second or so, though, the connection gets re-established and I am able to type and use the mouse buttons in the UAC prompt. Once the prompt clears, the connection drops again for a second, and then gets re-established again.

Is this something to do with configuration or perhaps should I just chalk it up to a change in behavior in version 1.4.10?

**EDIT**: Updated to 1.4.11. Still the same issue. Now it's with a Windows 8 Pro 64-bit client and a CentOS 6.4 server.

Comment: Been running in to this same problem since 1.4.10 myself. Sounds like just this version to me. Maybe try a nightly build?

Comment: Hang on, was it possible to interact with UAC before 1.4.10? I never noticed the elevate option before this version.

Comment: @r.tanner.f I was previously running the 1.4 beta, which added the ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://blog.synergy-project.org/2012/07/30/synergy-1-4-10-released/comment-page-1/#comment-5906), you have to click "Elevate" in the GUI.

For your info, Synergy lead, [Nick Bolton is on StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/20131/nbolton) and [Twitter](http://twitter.com/NickBoltonUK) and there is an [issue list](https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues). Also there's an [official Twitter account](http://twitter.com/SynergyDev).

There is a **[bug ticket for this issue](https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/3241)** and it has 'High' Priority. There's also some code that attempts to fix it. It might be helpful to the developers if you posted your findings in the ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I did, but I'll check it out tomorrow (I'm working from home today, and have no need for Synergy in my home office).

Comment: I just checked. I already have **Elevate** checked in the GUI. So, this, unfortunately, isn't the solution.

Comment: I believe that if you don't have Elevate selected it won't work <i>at all</i> with a UAC dialog up.

Comment: @Lake Yes, that's true. It works, but that initial disconnect/reconnect is the issue.

Comment: Right. I was pointing out that if you're having the disconnect/reconnect symptom then you necessarily have Elevate enabled because if you didn't the symptom would be more like "Synergy doesn't work at all with a UAC Dialog". =)